# How to use a created column as a JOIN parameter SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 Tables of Data which i am trying to Join (`TEXTDATA, STOREDATA, SALESDATA`). My TEXTDATA has a name string within on of the columns so have created a substring to find it.

I am trying to then used that newly formed string (`name`) as the basis to join to the SALESDATA table.

Here is my code

```
SELECT b.*,
       a.text,
       a.textname,
       SUBSTRING(a.[textname], CHARINDEX('/ ', a.[textname]) + 1, 11) AS NAME,
       c.[Sales],
       c.[Customer],
       c.[Class]
FROM   [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b
            ON  a.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
            ON  NAME = c.FirstName
```

With the error saying `Invalid column name 'name'`

Any ideas on how to reference the new column made later in a query?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You need to use a subquery or a CTE. `Name` is an alias, there's no column name `name`.

Comment: where do you want to use the column 'name'? show some pseud code so we can see what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks guys i will post some psuedo code now

Comment: Try to run it without alias `name` does it run

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest option is just to use the same formula in the LEFT JOIN's ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
    ON SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) = c.FirstName
```

Or you could put the formula in a CTE abstraction of your TEXTDATA table:

```
;with cte AS (
    SELECT [ID_TEXTDATA], text, textname, SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) as name
    From [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a 
)
SELECT b.*
,cte.text
,cte.textname
,cte.name
,c.[Sales]
,c.[Customer]
,c.[Class]
From 
    cte
INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b 
    on  cte.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
    on cte.name = c.FirstName
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select b.*
,a.text
,a.textname
,SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) as name
,c.[Sales]
,c.[Customer]
,c.[Class]

From 
    [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b 
    on  a.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
    on SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) = c.FirstName
```

First, join takes place and can't find the name

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this in your **ON CLAUSE**:

`SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11)`

```
Select b.*,a.text,a.textname,SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) 
as name,c.[Sales] ,c.[Customer],c.[Class]
From [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b 
on  a.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]

LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
on SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11)  = c.FirstName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't reference the column alias `name` on the same level.

You have to use the entire expression on the `ON`

```
ON SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) = c.FirstName
```

Or you can make use of a `CTE` or derived query and compose the expression `name` in the `CTE` or derived query.

```
with Text_Data as
(
    SELECT *,
           SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) as [name]
    FROM   [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a 
)
Select b.*
      ,a.text
      ,a.textname
      ,a.name
      ,c.[Sales]
      ,c.[Customer]
      ,c.[Class]    
From 
     Text_Data a 
INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b 
     on  a.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]    
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
    on a.name = c.FirstName
```

Or alternatively use a `CROSS APPLY` to compute the expression and then use it in the `JOIN`

```
Select b.*
      ,a.text
      ,a.textname
      ,n.name
      ,c.[Sales]
      ,c.[Customer]
      ,c.[Class]    
From 
    [dbo].[TEXTDATA] a 
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(a.[textname],CHARINDEX('/ ',a.[textname])+1,11) as name
) n
INNER JOIN [dbo].[STOREDATA] b 
    on  a.[ID_TEXTDATA] = b.[ID_STOREDATA]    
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[SALESDATA] c
    on n.name = c.FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

As the order of execution of SQL query says the select statement is run after all join statements so you can use alias in select for manipulation but not the same manipulated alias in join as join has already run by that time instead ypu need to have an extra select on top of it or using a `WITH CLAUSE Subquery`

```
   Select *, name from ( select *,.. as 
     name from table)  left join othertable
    t1 on 
    name=t1.value
```

Or using `WITH CLAUSE`

```
     WITH data as 
     ( select *,.. as name from table) 

    Select * from data left join table1 t1
    on data.name=t1.value
```